# In Python 2.7.x how to verify file writing is done to disk after .close()?

Tags: python, windows, file, disk

I am writing a tool in Python 2.7.x on Windows 10 / server 2016. As part of my program I write a file of variable size (could be 1KiB, could be 1GiB, or anything!) and I have been having an issue where things that happen after I call myFile.close() run into a care where the file hasn't been fully written to the disk yet even thought .close() was called and returned (no multi-threading or multi-processing here).

What is the best way in Python 2.7.x on a Windows 10/server2016 system to verify that all of the file contents I wanted pushed to the disk was actually done writing on that disk?

I know that a time.sleep(1) helps, but that's arbitrary and I don't know how fast the disk write speed actually is (range is from 1MB/s, to 3GB/s), and the file could be quite large! So I need something less arbitrary that can check that all of the file was fully written to disk before my tool continues to the next step.

Comment: At that point, Python itself is done with the file; the issue is Windows, or your filesystem (which could be NTFS, but could also be, say, SMB/CIFS for a network share), or even your disk interface card that's buffering things. It depends on how far you're willing to go and which of those you care about. Are you worried about opening the file in another app on the same system, or accessing it via a network share on another system, or not being corrupted if you flip the big red switch on the computer the moment the `close` finishes, or…?

Comment: @abarnert According to documentation, `os.fsync(fd)` forces write of file with filedescriptor `fd` to disk.

Comment: @DyZ On Windows, that calls [`_commit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/commit), which gets you past the OS's buffering, but not necessarily the filesystem or lower levels. So, as I said, it depends on how far you're willing to go and which levels you care about.

Comment: @abarnert According to the documentation, "The _commit function forces the operating system to write the file associated with fd to disk." What makes you think the file system is not a part of the OS? And what do you mean by "lower levels"?

Comment: @DyZ Notice that it's contrasting that with "not at the operating system's discretion". For, say, an SMB share, that means the file server is required to not send back the old data if you subsequently do a read from the same client. It doesn't guarantee any sequencing between clients, and flushing it to disk is only advisory. So, again, it depends on what you're actually worried about. And only the OP can tell us what the OP is worried about.

Comment: @abarnert The documentation clearly says: "This call ensures that the specified file is _flushed immediately_, not at the operating system's discretion." Why do you say flushing is advisory?

Comment: @DyZ The OS flushes the file. Which means it tells the file system to flush the file. That part is mandatory. But what the fjlesystem does with that is up to the filesystem. And for SMB, what it does is whatever it needs to ensure that a subsequent read by the same client will not get the earlier version. Which may not mean actually flushing to disk. (For a simpler example, consider the case of a transient RAM disk—it obviously isn’t writing anything to any persistent hardware when you ask it to flush. It just acts like a physical hard disk would have if it had written to disk.)

Comment: Without going into details about the test I'm trying to run (blah blah confidential info blah blah), I need the data of the file to be fully 100% done writing to the media on the drive (be it fully flashed NAND cells or fully programmed magnetic disk thingys). So all the way to the bottom level the write needs to be done before my program moves on.

Comment: OK, is it guaranteed to be a local disk? Guaranteed to be NTFS? If yes and yes, commit is all you need.

Comment: Yes, it is local and I don't see any real case for not using NTFS in this instance. So are you saying that when commit returns the data is guaranteed to have been fully written to media?

Answer (score 1):

You should call `fd.flush()`, followed by `os.fsync(fd)`, **before** closing the file. Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#files-and-directories

Comment: I don't think this question is answerable until the OP answers the comment, so I don't know whether this question is useful or useless yet. But I'm guessing the downvoter did so because you didn't explain what these functions are meant to do, or even provide a link to where to find that info. If so, it's somewhat better now, but downvoters usually don't come back, so…

Comment: You edited a link in after the initial posting. That’s why I said it’s better now. But unless you have a time machine, that isn’t likely to affect voting activity before the edit. And arguing with me about my guess about why some other person might have made a vote is even less likely to have an effect.

Comment: @abarnert Then I politely suggest you do not interpret the donwvoter's intentions.

Comment: This worked! I used file.write(data) -> time.sleep(2) -> file.flush() -> time.sleep(2) file.close() -> time.sleep(2). The rest of the code now runs along happily that the data is in fact stored on the target media.